# Serialization : SerialVersion UID generation process

Tags: java, serialization

If we are transferring state of an object from machine A to machine B , then successful serialization/deserialization will only work if both the machines have same SerialVersion UID of the class to which the transferred object belongs to.

I want to know if the generation of serial version UID is done by JVM , then how do I ensure that it will be the same on both the machines A and B before initiating the serialization process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, **don't use Java Serialization**. The only red highlighted text in the [Secure Coding Guidelines for Java SE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#8)  reads

> Note: Deserialization of untrusted data is inherently dangerous and
>   should be avoided.

To ensure the ID is the same define the `serialVersionUID` in the class.

```
@Serial private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

(`@Serial` is since the current version of Java, Java SE 14.)

To find the ID, first the `serialVersionUID` is looked for, and if not present it is calculated as specified in the docs (a hash of public methods and fields of the class).

Answer (score 1):

Question is asked in the Serialization documentation of Java, short answer, It is strongly recommended that you declare your own JVM serial number of type long static and final, if a serializable class does not explicitly declare a serialVersionUID, then the serialization runtime will calculate a default serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects of the class.

JVM does the work of checking and ensuring your serialized object has the same UID as when it is de-serialized.